# Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist

Tags: jquery, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I want to use autocomplete for jQuery in Eclipse. The Aptana Plugin is installed:

```
Aptana Web Development Tools
Version: 1.5.1.25495-787Y07jbcbrChz-Tq2k383275
```

Support for jQuery also:

```
Aptana Support for jQuery
Version: 1.3.2.00005
```

JavaScript/WTP is installed:

```
JavaScript Developer Tools
Version: 1.1.1.v200906091427-77-FGBCcNBC-BeMcEeOm
Build id: 20090616035105
```

But the autocomplete doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea of where the problem could be?

Comment: This was very helpful...i am new to Aptana and I struggled with adding support for jQuery1.4 (am using Aptana2, as v3 has no js debugging). If you have the same problem, go to this page - install the plugin for jQuery (https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/faqs/updating-changing-or-uninstalling/manual-plugin-install) -- then follow the jmohr's suggestions to activate the code assist

Comment: See this question for Aptana3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3

Comment: my question (and the answer) is 1,5 years older as the linked one and the problem was already solved....

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Turn on JavaScript Code Assist Feature

When you install additional AJAX library support the Code Assist for that library isn't turned on by default.

To turn on the Code Assist feature after you install additional AJAX Libraries:

```
Preferences > Aptana > Editors > JavaScript > Code Assist > Check jQuery
```

[image: Aptana AJAX Code Assist Settings]

### Switch to the Aptana Perspective

If you just installed the Aptana plugin and are trying to get this to work you'll have to make sure you're using the Aptana Perspective to utilize the AJAX library Code Assist feature:

```
Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Aptana
```

### Using Eclipse PDT with Aptana Plugin

I installed the Aptana plugin to Eclipse PDT and the jQuery Code Assist worked fine once I realized that I was still using the PDT PHP Perspective instead of the Aptana Perspective.

When I switched to the Aptana Perspective it started working.

#### Install Aptana Plugin before PDT

Sirokov pointed out that he was unable to get the Code Assist to work with PDT and Aptana Plugin unless he installed the Aptana Plugin first and then installed PDT second.

Comment: Updated way for Aptana Studio 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3

Comment: what's this "additional AJAX library" ? how can i install it? thanks

Answer (score 8):

I actually Had a hard time finding out how to install Aptana Plugins , so I am adding this in hopes that if someone else is confused they find it helpful.

whether in Aptana itself or eclipse its the same.

Help >> Install Aptana Features . you will find all the plugins here

took me like 30 minutes to find it hopefully I can save that for someone else

Comment: I don't have this option in Help, it's like a nightmare. I need it just for content assist for YUI. I'm using the current 3.0beta aptana eclipse plugin

Comment: Man, I have 3.0 and this is bullshit. I dont have half of these features. I dont even see the Help>>Install Aptana features.

Answer (score 4):

Also read this to get the code complete working.

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/356-jquery-code-assist-no-utility-function-support

Basically, you need to update the File Associations to make *.js files use the Aptana editor.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question as well.

What I use is the [JSDT jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/) for Eclipse Indigo (has to be this version though)
It has basic functionality, but I like it.  There is an installation guide in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/wiki/Installation).

I also use Notepad++ for the autocomplete outside of Eclipse and to run jQuery snippets in a stand alone mode.
The plugin for Notepad++ is located [here](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/11/26/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/).