# How to enable jQuery Intellisense in Aptana?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana

I have Aptana and i installed Aptana Support for jQuery plugin.

Now i oped a javascript file, but can't see any jQuery Intellisense,

How to enable that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist)

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way is to create a project in Aptana - you can choose which libraries to include in your project.  Then pull the .js file into your project.  It should give you jQuery intellisense then.

Comment: Brendan is correct. The project itself has to be associated with the JQuery library, which creates a /lib folder inside the project. If you don't have this in the project and didn't select JQuery as the language to use, it won't work.

Comment: Also, this link may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist

Comment: @S Pangborn in fact this answered exactly my question, can you put your comment as an answer so that i accept as right answer?

Answer (score 0):

An additional way to achieve this (if all else fails I guess) is to download the file from https://raw.github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble/master/support/jquery.1.4.2.sdocml and drop it into the root of your project folder. This should give you intellisense in Aptana 3 (at least) where I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

**Commands > Bundle Development > Install Bundle** then select **jQuery**. Now jQuery appear in the Commands menu, ans you can use jQuery Snippets and intelisense.

I thinks that this only works in js files and not in script tag in HTML file.