# Aptana 3.0 no syntax hints for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana 3.0.

How to enable jQuery syntax tips (intellisence)?

**THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE.
That answer is for version 2.0.
There is not menu called Code Assist in 3.0.**

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526658/how-to-enable-jquery-intellisense-in-aptana

Comment: @M.Babcock No. It is not duplicate. I'm talking about 3.0. It is totally difrent then 2.0.

Comment: This SO question should help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3/4725870#4725870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is bug.
I submited it to bug site.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions suggesting that you download the jQuery "bundle" do seem to "work". Ish.

I did my best to document the workarounds here: http://karoshiethos.com/2012/05/11/hacking-code-assist-in-aptana-3-javascript/