# How can I get Aptana's code assist to work with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, intellisense, aptana, content-assist

There's a Google Maps API v3 [Visual Studio Intellisense Helper](http://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/), which presumably works great for Visual Studio, but Aptana (based on Eclipse) uses a different JavaScript documentation format - [ScriptDoc](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Documenting_your_code_using_ScriptDoc) (.sdoc files). ScriptDoc is also the name of a [VS utility](http://ajaxdoc.codeplex.com/) to convert JS files with Intellisense comments into XML, just to confuse things.

I've tried adding the Intellisense files as file / global references in Aptana, but all this gives is completion for the word `google` and no completion or documentation in the google namespace.

Possible solutions:

- Find someone who's already done this for Aptana. I've Google'd quite a bit already but couldn't find anything.
- Convert the Visual Studio Intellisense Helper into a format Aptana can understand.
- Scrape the [API page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html) and convert it into a format Aptana can understand.

Comment: Doesn't say how, but here is it working in v2 - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IwBS2uO_es

Answer (score 1):

Can't you put the JS file in the Project's references ?

Comment: I've tried http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/1/6/main.js (and a few others) but it's not coming back with anything. Even if this worked for code completion (which would be nice), it won't have any of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Aptana and ScriptDoc is the worst decision they made and they seem to be attached to it, it's the main reason I have considered switching to Eclipse.
I've been thinking in using jsdoc-toolkit to generate .sdoc files from jsdoc notations (using some type of templates), but to use .sdoc files you must insert @id tags all over your code, and that discouraged me.

Comment: Cannot agree more to your comment. http://swik.net/Eclipse/del.icio.us%2Ftag%2Feclipse/Documenting+Your+Code+Using+ScriptDoc+%2F+Using+Code+Assist+%2F+FAQs+-+Aptana+Studio+Support/d6d5r

Answer (score 1):

This helper is for Visual Studio. I don't think Aptana can work with vsdoc.js files

[Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist)

Answer (score 1):

I found this and I'm checking if it helps
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns%2Fmaps