# Google Maps JS API in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, google-maps

I'd like to have an "autocomplete" functionality in Eclipse for Google Maps JavaScript API.
For example:

I write:

```
map = new google.maps.
```

and then I'd like Eclipse to offer appropriate methods - like this:

```
Map
Marker
Polyline
Polygon
...
```

etc.
see
http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Is that possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best autocomplete I've seen for Eclipse is by installing the Aptana plugin from http://www.aptana.com/. I haven't actually done this, but if you downloaded the Maps JS file and added it to your project, that should be enough to get autocompletion for at least the class and function names.

Comment: But how to get it working... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697501/how-can-i-get-aptanas-code-assist-to-work-with-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Where to get the Maps JS file?

Comment: Well, if you look at the Network tab when browsing in Chrome, you'll see the maps JS file that the Google API downloads. That's the one to get. For instance, the one it gets right now is at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/14/11/main.js but obviously that URL changes as the API version updates.