# os x aptana jquery content assist doesn't work with php

Tags: php, jquery, macos, aptana, content-assist

Hello I'm running aptana studio 2 standalone on os X 10.6 and I've never been able to get a proper jquery auto-complete to work in a PHP project.

Php code completion works. Inside an .html file jQuery and html completes nicely as well. But to my frustration it doesn't complete inside a php file in a php project! And yes I've tried both the php and aptana perspectives.

I also looked at this [Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist)
And I scoured google for a good month to get a clue on the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so the usual javascript works it's jQuery that's giving me problems. Neither $. generate anything nor does $("document").

Answer (score 1):

I had this code completion fuzz in Aptana Studio, too.
A bigger problem was the missing code completion for selfmade PHP-Classes that are extending other PHP-Classes.

That was one of the reasons for me to switch to another editor.
I recommend you to give WebStorm or PHPStorm from JetBrains a try. Altough this is not a free editor (it costs about 50 bucks at the moment, but is free to try for 30 days) its really worth the try.
Its small, fast and: the code completion and inspection works like a charm. Even HTML and JavaScript completion inside an  works!

It even brings FTP and SVN/CVS/GIT support. Everything you need for handling small to big projects. I completely abandoned Aptana in favor for PHPStorm.

Comment: I tried it and couldn't get it to debug files called through ajax - is  it possible? Aptana does it

Comment: so i've switched to phpstorm  and it definitely works better for php and javascript. From some comments i've seen Aptana is really gearing towards ruby on rails rather than php.