# Is there any software with intellisense for Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense

I want to start learning jQuery, but there's so much you can do with it. I'm interested in using PHP as well.

I understand that Visual Studio has intellisense for Javascript, but isn't that for ASP.NET? Can you build PHP applications in Visual Studio?

Comment: it's duplicate. Please search in the form before posting. This question had been asked many times already.

Comment: @A_Var - in searching and typing in my question, most of the results were issues with or questions about Visual Studio's intellisense. I did not see any questions relating to software *alternative to* VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Aptana Studio](http://docs.aptana.com/) with such support as well as full featured PHP editor.

See:

- [Aptana Studio makes jQuery so much easier](http://www.codescene.com/2009/04/aptana-studio-makes-jquery-so.php)
- [Code Assist for jQuery](http://www.bitstorm.org/edwin/jquery/)

[image]

Comment: @zolex: I would same answer because i answered before :)

Comment: yea 2 seconds, i see you pimped your posting, well, you win ;) but now there is a good answer for a visual studio inntegration...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse aptana studio in eclipse PDT. [Plugging Aptana to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist). Aptana has some intellisense for jQuery but beware that it's not complete since Javascript is a dynamic language and it's difficult to get a complete one.

Buy my honest take on jQuery intellisense. If you want to be a jQuery expert dump the intellisense part. Javascript is a dynamic language and that is the reason why these editors never work as intended. I used VisualStudio recently and never got what I intended.

Comment: I use Aptana with the jQuery plugin offered on the plugins page and it works fine. Installing it wasn't the simplest thing in the world, and one time I installed it and it crashed Eclipse every time I pressed ctrl-space, but once it's installed without having broken, it works fine. :-)

Comment: @treeface I was in the same boat too while configuring the plugin. But aptana works better than VS 2010 when it comes to jQuery intellisense.

Comment: I haven't used VS 2010, so I can't speak to it, but I agree that Aptana's (or, I suppose, Eclipse's) jQuery support is fairly good.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Visual Studio to have intellisense for jQuery - see [jQuery 1.4.1 Intellisense with Visual Studio](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx) on Scott Gutherie's blog. Not for VS 2008 you need to [install this patch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx).

Comment: this seems to answer the question even better than switching ide to aptana ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can build any applications with visual studio, but visual studio is waste...
have a look at eclipse, aptana's js editor has jQuery autocompletion.

Comment: when you say that Visual Studio is a waste is it actually your personal experience talking?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes it is, sorry i forgot "imo" :D