# How do I enable jQuery intellisense in Eclipse and/or Aptana

Tags: jquery, eclipse, intellisense, aptana, code-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and jQuery code assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist)

I've got Eclipse running with the Aptana addon and would like to have jQuery intellisense/code-complete, e.g. I would like "css()" etc. to pop up in the following example:
[image]

I tried to set this in Aptana preferences but it doesn't seem to have support for jQuery, no checkbox:

[image]

**How can I get jQuery code complete in Eclipse and/or Aptana?**

Comment: Is the aptana perspective selected?

Comment: @Hosam Not really a duplicate. The answer of the question you link to, is here the question : Where's that checkbox?

Comment: You're right @Joris. Thanks for the notice!