# How to enable jQuery support in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: jquery, intellisense, aptana

How Can I Enable jQuery In Aptana Studio 3 (beta) ?

I didn't see any document for this version.

Does Aptana Studio 3 (beta) Supporting jQuery?

Comment: very helpful :) thnx !!!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Studio 3 much of this sort of functionality is still coming as Aptana is going more of a TextMate bundle route for a great deal of their features, which I think is really cool.

That said, there is already a jQuery bundle. The jQuery bundle, if you don't have it installed yet, can be installed from Aptana via the Commands menu **(Commands->Bundle Development->Install Bundle and then select jQuery from the list)**.

This support discussion has some details about jQuery code assist in Aptana:
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2006-studio-3-jquery-support-is-lacking

In particular, it mentions adding a jquery vs doc file (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js) to your project. This seems to be the key.

If you install the jQuery bundle and add the aforementioned JS file, you can get jQuery code hints in your Aptana editor(s). I just ran through this in one of my Rails projects and it does work (I'm on the latest beta of Studio 3 for Mac).

Comment: Notice that Aptana3 jQuery support is a naive. It only adds a completion for *known functions*. If you create `$.fn.test = function () {}` it does not recognize it as a plugin and cannot auto-complete.

Answer (score 13):

This is incorrect. While this will give you jQuery snippets and some commands, to actually add jQuery content assist, all you have to add is a single file. Please follow the instructions here instead:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

Answer (score 2):

to have code assist with aptana 3 follow this instructions
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support (i.e. Commands-> Bundle dev->Install-> select jquery)
and put your jquery.js library in your project as usual (drop it in a folder of your choice)

Answer (score 1):

I just spent the last hour trying to get this working.

Eclipse's support for javascript is terrible.  I've tried VJET and aptana.  A simple code complete that includes string.replace() won't appear.

For anyone else hitting this page, I would say this:  Don't even bother.  Eclipse simply isn't a javascript IDE.