# jQuery on New Aptana Studio 3

Tags: jquery, aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 in my windows 7. I tried to code some jQuery using Aptana. But it give no code completion. After reading [How to enable jQuery support in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enabling-jquery-in-aptana-studio-3) , I tried to do like the answerer said. Command->Install Bundle->jQuery but after clicking OK I got message on console

```
This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found.
Please correct the problem and restart the IDE.
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed Aptana Studio, did you choose to install a version of Git? Without the Git support, it can't install the jQuery ruble.

That said, you don't need to even do that. The simplest approach is to follow the instructions here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

You just need to drop a single file into your project.

Comment: Thank you... it`s woriking now :D

Comment: it works like crap though, Dreamweaver cs5.5(its either 5.5 or 5.1 i forgot) works amazingly, it's awesome, works just how it should. Aptana just can't get it right, though, intellisense got better with pressing TAB, instead of Ctrl+Space(which is a horrible key combination to bring up the intellisense menu, it should appear automatically like Dreamweavers, or at the very least, pop up when pressing tab)

Comment: Many content assist options appear automatically when pressing tab. Is there a specific example you are referring to? You can also configure what tabs cause CA to pop up in preferences.

Comment: Hmm..I'm missing some completions, e.g .val() and .post(), is that normal for jQuery 1.6.2 bundle ?