# Support of jQuery mobile in Aptana

Tags: jquery-mobile, aptana, aptana3

i'm searching for a developement bundle to extend the functionality of aptana to support jQuery Mobile code. Does anybody know a good plugin?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any code assist for JQuery Mobile in aptana but i found out that [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-studio) offers JQuery Mobile support. It's another Eclipse-based IDE that is designed for mobile web developpement.

See this Stackoverflow question that helped me : [jQuery Mobile Content Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834459/jquery-mobile-content-assist)

Answer (score 0):

You can activate it as a bundle, for more info refer to @craig.kaminsky answer in this question, I used it and it works:

[How to enable jQuery support in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3)

If you don't have git installed and find any issues this may be of help:

[jQuery on New Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449863/jquery-on-new-aptana-studio-3)