# jQuery Mobile Content Assist

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile, eclipse-plugin, aptana, content-assist

I have searched everywhere, does anyone know how to get jQuery Mobile content assist in Eclipse. I am running indigo, and I have Aptana 3 installed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the closest help I could find.
http://camcollins.com/2012/01/adventures-in-ios-land-day-1/

Keep in mind, Titanium Studio and not Aptana has the jQuery Mobile supports. Aptana has no plans to include those, to my knowledge. So, either use Eclipse with Titanium as a plug in, or download the Studio here
http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-studio