# Best IDE for jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've started learning the jquery mobile framework so I can bring my existing website to the mobile space.  I see they have many [Apps and Frameworks](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/#Apps) listed for development but they all seem to be cloud based or require a monthly subscription.

Are there any free tools to aid in the development of a mobile website using jquery mobile?  If so what do you recommend?

Comment: You should check jetbrains official student bundle offer. You can get online free student licence in 20 seconds for all these ides. [https://www.jetbrains.com/student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Aptana](http://aptana.com/) with jQuery bundle installed.
[How to enable jQuery support in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: But he's asking "jQuery Mobile" support, not "jQuery" support?

Answer (score 7):

Believe it or not, Dreamweaver 5.5 is a good editor for jQuery Mobile. Adobe shipped it with built in support (code hinting, syntax highlighting, etc.) for both jQuery itself and jQuery Mobile. This includes data attributes, and more.

Answer (score 4):

Install Eclipse for javascript developers here is the link
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ 
and then install the Aptana plugin here is the link
http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download

Or you can directly try Aptana Studio standalone version for jquery mobile development.

Paid tools for jQuery Mobile development and the best one upto now is Adobe Dreamweaver it has many drag and drop feature for jQUery Mobile development.
Dreamweaver has pre loaded jQuery Mobile Templates.

Most simple and best editor which i use is Notepad++.

Comment: Notepad++ is OK as editor for jQM but I prefer Sublime 3 - amazing!

Answer (score 2):

its free tools to aid in the development of a mobile website using jquery mobile
better you use

https://01.org/rapid-interface-builder/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Just a "heads up". Dreamweaver cs6 does NOT include the built in support to create JQMobile apps yourself. Adobe has now tied Dreamweaver mobile development to their cloud based service. I'm sticking with DW 5.5. It has some problems related to creating mobile apps.Still, with some tinkering it does the job without yet another paid service.

DW is a great ide for mobile development. I have several apps in the Apple store that were created with 5.5.

-Rachel